# BND ignores ".impl." packages

Tags: osgi, bnd

According to a comment to answer related to BND, it does not export packages named ".impl.":

> ok, never mind. **I found that some packages were named ".impl." in the code, and BND does not export them by default.** I renamed the packages and this solved this particular problem. look like the error message wasn't too specific. – Alex [Sep 12 '11 at 19:20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374524/bnd-puts-the-same-package-to-both-export-and-import-sections-of-manifest-mf#comment8928778_7375368)

Is there a reliable way to make BND always export those packages for wildcard exports like `foo.*`?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a Bnd thing. That is a `maven-bundle-plugin` thing. `maven-bundle-plugin` [configures Bnd with some behavior](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#default-behavior).